# OpenGL: How to write into a texture channel by channel, by sampling and rendering to the same texture

Tags: opengl, textures, fragment-shader

The scenario is:
I have a texture A.
There are 3 loops. Each loop writes a channel into the texture A.
After the 3 loops, all 3 channels in A are updated.

The shader is like:

```
vec3 tmpVec3 = texture(inputTexture0, vUV).rgb; // inputTexture0 is texture A tmpVec3[channelIndex_P] = texture(inputTexture1, vUV).r;  // write one channel from inputTexture1

color = vec4(tmpVec3, 1.0);
```

It render to texture A, that is inputTexture0.
In this way by rendering and sampling the same texture, I can save memory by one texture.

However, the result is not desired.

I read the article "[Sampling and Rendering to the Same Texture](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_:_common_mistakes#Sampling_and_Rendering_to_the_Same_Texture)".
It says:

> "Meaning it may do what you want, the sampler may get old data, the
>   sampler may get half old and half new data, or it may get garbage
>   data. Any of these are possible outcomes."

But since the writing data of the specific pixel always happens after getting data of the specific pixel, why is it not possible?

Another article "[Sampling from and rendering to the same texture and parallel sorting / hashing](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/184838-Sampling-from-and-rendering-to-the-same-texture-and-parallel-sorting-hashing)"
It says:

> "But if the result in every framebuffer pixel would be the value of
>   one of the fragments which wrote to that pixel and not a combination
>   of values from multiple fragments, this functionality would still be
>   useful for parallel sorting / hashing algorithms implemented in glsl."

I do not understand the above words. Does it say under some situations "sampling and rendering to the same texture" can be used and have defined result. Then how to do it? How to solve my current situation, since I want to save one texture variable.

Comment: What version of OpenGL are you targeting? GL4 has image Load/Store that will help you with this, but you'll have to implement synchronization yourself.

Comment: OpenGL 3.2. My confusion is: here I always write to the same pixel that reading happens before. So why doesn't it work? And what does the second link imply that under some situations it can work?

Comment: You can do that using [texture barriers](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/texture_barrier.txt) on NV hardware. I don't know if other vendors ever adopted that extension, considering it basically became obsolete when computer shaders and image load/store were added.

Comment: Thanks. So would you please explain why my situation cannot work around, since the writing and reading of interest processes are not at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

> So would you please explain why my situation cannot work around, since the writing and reading of interest processes are not at the same time.

They absolutely are processed at the same time, I think you are not understanding how shaders are scheduled on the GPU. Fragment shaders do not run in serial, and your attempt to write to the texture will not necessarily complete before a parallel invocation reads the same texture (nor is there any guarantee that the texture memory will not be cached; making changes to the memory invisible).

This is why you need barriers. A texture barrier (NV specific extension) or a general purpose memory barrier will cause your shader invocations to stall at the barrier until every single instance of the shader finishes reading or writing, and then proceed. This will prevent data hazards that would result in reading the wrong data.

To do this in a GL3 class implementation, texture barriers may be your only option. In GL4.2+ image load/store would be the preferred approach, and some older implementations support this through the [`GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_image_load_store.txt) extension.

Without any of those things, however, what you are trying to do right now invokes undefined behavior. You need some sort of synchronization construct to do this correctly, and that is where barriers come in.

Comment: Thank you. But I just don't understand. If the fragment shaders do not run in serial, in my example even if I do not let sampling and rendering the same texture happen, reading must happen before writing to make the shader work: where is my understanding wrong?

Comment: @user1914692: No, that behavior only applies to coherent memory. The output of a fragment shader does not need to be written and cache invalidated before a texture is sampled, and in fact it usually is not unless you use image load/store with the `coherent` qualifier. Moreover, adjacent fragments will sample a 2x2 window of texels (if you use `GL_LINEAR` filtering, which is the default) and the neighboring texels won't even be computed yet.

Comment: @user1914692: Shaders were never intended to work the way you're trying to use them right now, so GLSL compilers do all sorts of caching and other optimizations that don't work correctly when you try to read/write the same memory. But extensions were created that allow you to synchronize and disable these optimizations so that what you are doing does not create undefined behavior.

Comment: Sorry I am a little dumb. For the code in one shader program, it IS serial, right? If it is not serial, we can randomly exchange lines in the shader program. Or would you give me some links to understand it more thoroughly?

Comment: @user1914692: I really don't know how to explain it any better than I already have. Reading and writing to the same memory produces undefined behavior because shaders are not supposed to work that way. You can easily wind up reading cached values. You need coherent memory to ensure that changes made to the texture memory are _visible_.  You also need synchronization since you are doing this in three loops as your question explains. You don't want to read the texture memory again until it's finished writing.

Comment: @user1914692: In fact, after seeing what you are actually trying to do here. A texture barrier is not going to be adequate. You will absolutely need image load/store for this to work. You are trying to read and then write to the same texel. If you don't want to use image load/store (which is a GL 4.2 feature) then you will have to ping-pong between two textures, or use a texture twice the size and read from one half and write to the other half. You are not allowed to read and write the same texel in a single shader invocation even using `NV_texture_barrier`.

Comment: Right now I am doing ping-pong technique. My current program has 3 loops. If there is only 1 loop, do you think sampling and rendering to the same texture will work? Could you refer to some links regarding how shader implement, like you said cached values. Thanks.

Comment: is it possible to advise some links for me about how shader works in terms of parallel processing? Thanks.